# i need The app regularly downloads and processes small amounts of content from the network(swift)

Tags: swift

I've written an HTTP connection and I receive information(post method).I need the information in the background to be checked and, if necessary, warn the program.
in the other words i need The app regularly downloads and processes small amounts of content from the network.
What should I do?
Is the use of a timer in the background is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should get a server to do this work and send a push notification to the device when something of interest happens.

You can not do this from the device (certainly not on a prescribed schedule that you decide upon).

Comment: ? about a server service that runs periodic code for you and allows you to send push notifications - google is your friend

Comment: Thank you
Dear friend
so background fetch, what does it do?

Comment: it does what you think, just not on a regular schedule that you want, the device decides when it should be done based on a number of criteria like when the user uses you app, how long your app takes to download, how often it actually gets new data...